# How Do I deploy/undeploy SOA Application such as BPEL processes using weblogic.deployer tool

Tags: weblogic, soa, bpel

I am currently using a script to deploy applications to weblogic and it works fine for war's on the AdminServicer

```
java -classpath $webLogicJarLocation weblogic.Deployer -username $username -password $password -name $OldAppName -undeploy
```

It may be this is not possible but I would Imagine it is. currently I keep getting `No application named 'HelloBPELProject' exists for operation undeploy`

I have tried setting the `-targets` flag as shown below but with no luck

```
java -classpath $webLogicJarLocation weblogic.Deployer -username $username-password $password -name HelloBPELProject -undeploy -targets soa_server1
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

`java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -password weblogic1 -listapps`

To see if your application is actually deployed and the name matches what you think it should. The output should look like the following:

`weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -listapps`

`HelloBPELProject`

`Number of Applications Found : 1`